# Does concourse task override docker image entrypoint?

Tags: docker, concourse

I have a pipeline that looks like this:

```
jobs:
- name: master
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: master-git
    trigger: true
  - get: my-build-image
  - task: "Run integration tests"
    image: my-build-image
    privileged: true
    config:
      platform: linux
      inputs:
      - name: master-git
      outputs:
      - name: build-workspace
      run:
        dir: master-git
        path: make
        args:
        - ci
```

The 'my-build-image' is a docker image that has an entrypoint that runs some commands before running whatever command is provided, using https://github.com/progrium/entrykit.

The problem seems to be that, when Concourse (or Garden) runs the docker container using my-build-image, it is overriding the entrypoint because those commands don't seem to be executed anymore.

I'm trying with a local deployment for Concourse (with docker-compose), so I have access to all the setup. However, I'm fairly new to Concourse, so I'm not sure where to look for logs and stuff like that.

Comment: I think this is translated to a call like this in Garden:

process, err := container.Run(garden.ProcessSpec{
  Path: "echo",
  Args: []string{"hello from the container"},
}, garden.ProcessIO{
  Stdout: buffer,
  Stderr: buffer,
})

However, I'm still unclear what Garden will do with the container entrypoint and CMD.

Comment: I guess it will mount the layered file system, i.e. the image, and then execute the command under `run`